# localhost vs. server PHP version

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Wordpress site using my localserver which runs PHP 5.6.7. When I tried to upload the db to my shared server's phpMyAdmin, I got an error because apparently it runs only up to PHP 5.4. I created a whole site on a version my server doesn't support! What's the least painful solution to this dilemma?

Comment: 1) Verify if your provider support multiple php version (most provider offer this option); 2) ... modify your php code (I'm sorry for you, but so it is...)

Comment: http://php.net/supported-versions.php — PHP 5.4 stopped getting security updates last year. Get a better host.

Comment: If you're hosting provider gave your cPanel with your hosting (*most likely they did*), you should be able to change the PHP version. You'll find it in the "PHP Configuration".

Comment: If you decide to change your code, and If you use an IDE, (I don't know if they all do this, but I remember that Netbeans did when I used it last) you can specify a PHP version for your project and it will identify errors based on that version.

Answer (score 0):

PHP version of the server doesn't affect while uploading the database. At the same time the PHP v5.6.7 with PHP 5.4 doesn't matters in wordpress. The problem with be on your MySQL server. It should be greater than MySQL 5.5.3

In WordPress 4.2 tables upgraded from `utf8` to `utf8mb4`, Refe this [link](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/)

In order to solve this, while exporting your database export with MySQL 4 compatible and then import it. Also change your `DB_CHARSET` to utf8 on `wp-config`.Refer this [link](https://help.blacknight.com/entries/35979351-Migrate-WordPress-from-utf8mb4-to-utf8)

Let me know if this solve the problem. Otherwise let me know the problem with brief(On error log)